# Editor Design: Update Swing Components After Change

Tags: java, swing

In my editor I have a **LayersManager** and a **LayersView** class. The LayersManager class holds all the layers that the user is currently using (think Photoshop layers). The LayersView is a JPanel that lists the layers contained in the LayersManager.

What I would like to do is to update the LayersView JPanel by adding or removing a LayerComponent from the JPanel's container whenever the add(Layer) or remove(Layer) methods are called from the LayersManager.

In other words, what I want is a reverse ChangeListener where whenever a change is made in the LayersManager, the LayersView is automatically contacted, adds or removes a LayerComponent from it's container and invalidates itself.

So my questions are: Is there a standard built in listener to do this? Are listeners the right way to go? Or should I just include a reference to the LayersView inside the LayersManager and manually call the required methods (I suspect this is bad design)? I can't think of a nice (design wise) way of implementing my own listeners.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). Java has built-in support for this pattern in the form of the [Observable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html) and [Observer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Observer.html) classes.

Basically, your `LayersManager` would extend `Observable` and your `LayersView` would implement `Observer`. You would then call `addObserver` on the `LayersManager` and pass in your `LayersView`.

Once that is in place you can call the following methods on your `LayersManager` whenever a change occurs that you want to notify the `LayersView` about:

```
layersManager.setChanged();
layersManager.notifyObservers();
```

The `notifyObservers` method can take an object as a parameter if you want the `Observer` listeners to receive some data. Once `notifyObservers` is called, your `LayersView` will have the `update` method called.

Comment: I like the proposal, but there is no need to extend the Observer class - they can be composed in the LayerManager/VIew class, or that support can be written from scratch (it's a fairly small amount of code)

Comment: @linski You're correct, I removed the line about needing to be extended. The Observer is an interface, so that's a non-issue.

Comment: Thanks Linski, I was actually planning to do something like that! Seeing the Observer pattern again just helped me come up with a way of tackling the problem myself.